# Filter function in R throws data missing

Tags: r, regression, marketing

I am trying to develop a Multivariate linear regression, in R 3.2.2,  using

> Ad GRP

and

> Ad Spending

to predict Sales.

This is my GRP Data

```
adGRPAugToDec <- c(2020, 1278, 1195, 1310, 495)
```

This is my adstock function , based on this blogpost [MMM](https://analyticsartist.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/marketing-mix-modeling-explained-with-r/)

```
    # Define Adstock Function
adstock <- function(x, rate=0){
 return(as.numeric(filter(x=x, filter=rate, method="recursive")))
}
```

I call the above function like this

```
ad.adstock <- adstock(adGRPAugToDec,0.5)
```

I get this error

> Error in filter_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) :
>   argument ".data" is missing, with no default

Comment: I get no error. Your function definition lacks a closing curly bracket.

Comment: Sorry @JeremyMiles i missed the curly bracket in the question. Also, if you get no error, are you using R Studio ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` function you want to run, from the base package `stats` -- `stats::filter` -- is being over-ridden by `dplyr::filter`, since you are probably also loading `dplyr`. You can either write `stats::filter()` explicitly wherever you want to use `filter`, or change which filter is used in the global namespace by default by running the line of code `filter = base::filter`.